# responsive map not showing under 550px

Tags: html, css, google-maps

On this [live page](http://isellrye.com/contact.html) the map looks great except when you size down to view on smaller devices, appro under 550px. This is my code for that part for that section. What do I have to change to show the map for mobile or smaller devices? thank you

```css
.columns
{
    width:100%;
}
.left
{
    float:left;
    width:460px;
    
}
.right
{
    margin-left:500px;
}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
    <div class="left">
<p><b>Pebble Cove Motel</b></p> 
<p>741 Ocean Blvd</p> 
<p>Rye, NH 03870</p>
<p><a href="mailto:pebblecovemotel@comcast.net">PebbleCoveMotel@comcast.net</a></p>
<p>Phone: <a href="tel:6034368108">603-436-8108</a></p>
</div>
    <div class="right">
<div class="google-maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d186637.02907792313!2d-70.85793188067471!3d43.037147979147306!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89e2c0b2dad571d3%3A0xf0f66f2f40db8717!2sPebble+Cove+Motel!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1463168351650" width="450" height="450"></iframe>
</div>

</div></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the huge `margin-left` on `.right` causes it to shrink.

Use a media query to only use the float layout above a certain viewport width.  I added one to your CSS.  You can adjust the `min-width` value to suit your needs.  This will stack your items on smaller screens.

```css
.columns
{
    width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .left
  {
      float:left;
      width:460px;
  }
  .right
  {
      margin-left:500px;
  }
}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
    <div class="left">
<p><b>Pebble Cove Motel</b></p> 
<p>741 Ocean Blvd</p> 
<p>Rye, NH 03870</p>
<p><a href="mailto:pebblecovemotel@comcast.net">PebbleCoveMotel@comcast.net</a></p>
<p>Phone: <a href="tel:6034368108">603-436-8108</a></p>
</div>
    <div class="right">
<div class="google-maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d186637.02907792313!2d-70.85793188067471!3d43.037147979147306!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89e2c0b2dad571d3%3A0xf0f66f2f40db8717!2sPebble+Cove+Motel!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1463168351650" width="450" height="450"></iframe>
</div>

</div></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the width of your div .left. You should make the width of the .left and .right in %. Something like .left {width:50%;} .right{width:50%;}.

Comment: that didn't work, I think it must also have something to do with the google map css

Comment: Ok, try this: .left {float:none; width:100%;} .right{float:none; width:100%;} @media (min-width: 768) { .left { float: left; width: 50%;}  .right {float: left;width: 50%;}}

Comment: that works when it's smaller  https://s31.postimg.org/n8tah9a63/Capture2.png but when it's wider the map goes underneath, not it 2 columns like originally  https://s31.postimg.org/s7pj3yoob/Capture1.png this is what it should look like wide screen https://s32.postimg.org/dmzrod5r9/correct.png

Comment: Yes, so you can change the media query to any pixel size where you want it to go to two columns. Instead of min-width: 768 you can put 460 or something mobile phone size. In my personal opinion the address should be on one line and map beneath on mobile devices. Imagine address and the map on the same line on 320px (iPhone 4,5). The map will be too tiny for viewing.